# MYSQL - Select multiple rows in one query

Tags: php, mysql

claimId is foreign key

```
Table  (statusTable)
Id_          _chaseStatus_       _claimId_
1               Open               CL001
2               Close              CL002    
3               Open               CL001
4               Open               CL003
5               Open               CL001
6               Open               CL003



$query =    "SELECT * FROM statusTable ";
$query .=   "WHERE (`chaseStatus` = 'Open') ";
$query .=   "AND (id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM statusTable))";





while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){      
        $items[] = $row;
    }

    //$items = array_reverse($items ,true);

    foreach($items as $item){
      $claimId  = $item["claimId"];
      echo $claimId;
    }
```

My query gives me only one column which is highest id.

But I am trying to get only 'Open' from 'chaseStatus' for each 'claimId' (with highest id) like;

How can I get like this

> for id = 5 : CL001

AND

> for id = 6 : CL003

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the highest id of the claimid using group by.

```
$query =    "SELECT max(Id) as Id,claimId FROM statusTable ";
$query .=   "WHERE (`chaseStatus` = 'Open') ";
$query .=   "GROUP BY claimId";
```

THis should result in the following table

```
Id  claimId
5   CL001
6   CL003
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b000e/1

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want by including the `'Open'` condition in the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM statusTable
WHERE `chaseStatus` = 'Open' AND
      id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM statusTable WHERE chaseStatus = 'Open' GROUP By ClaimId);
```

I think it is redundant to have the `open` condition in the outer query, so this should work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM statusTable
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM statusTable WHERE chaseStatus = 'Open' GROUP BY ClaimId);
```

Comment: @Royertan . . . This would work better if you had more columns that you wanted to pull from each row.  With just three columns, his approach is very reasonable.

Comment: I tried but only get one result! which is 'max id'.I need each claimId (Only 'Open') but highest one.Thanks again